# Dimensionalized heat equation

Tags: thermodynamics, dimensional-analysis

The heat equation says that
$$\rho c \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= \kappa \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}~? $$

How could one devise a nondestructive experiment to say, find the thermal diffusivity i.e $\frac{\kappa}{\rho c}$?

Nondimensionalizing gives us $u_t=u_{xx}$
But how can this help us find $\frac{\kappa}{\rho c}$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "nondimensionalizing"?

Comment: @Filippo I think OP means,  looking for self similar solutions to a PDE using dimensional analysis.

Comment: @Ratman What do you mean by self similar?

Comment: @Filippo A self similar function in time is a function that, plotted in a certain set of coordinates (self similar coordinates), is stationary in time. (Thats probably not the best definition, but you can check wikipedia). By dimensional analysis you can show that the diffusion equation has self similar solution, this makes easier solve it, but the coefficent (thermal diffusivity) must still be derived by experiments. You can check "the devil is in details" by Batterman or "scaling, self similarity and intermediate asymptotics" by Barenblatt (I am reading the last one,  is very nice)

Comment: @Ratman Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 2):

You want to measure the [*thermal diffusivity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_diffusivity) $\alpha:=\frac{\kappa}{\rho c}$ in $u_t=\alpha u_{xx}$. This is done with the [flash method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_flash_analysis). As explained [here](https://nodo.ugto.mx/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Flash-Method-of-Detennining-Thennal-Diffusivity-Heat-Capacity-and-Thennal-Conductivity.pdf), the $0.1388$ coefficient is $\pi^{-2}$ times the value of $\omega$ satisfying$$\frac12=1+2\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^n\exp(-n^2\omega),$$i.e.$$\frac14=\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^{n-1}\exp(-n^2\omega).$$